# Robo cup 2d rcssserver 15 ready to use parser

Tags: parsing, robocup

I have installed `robocup 2d rcssserver 15.x.x` and a client team in my machine, I am trying to understand how server-client communication works in `robocup 2d` simulation.I need to know which parser(ready to use) is available for `"Robocup 2d simulator"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read server-manual (can be found in [sourceforge.org](http://sourceforge.org) )
or use a base code such as **agent2d** or **WEBase** or **UVA_Trilearn** base

Answer (score 0):

Some base codes have been already released. All of them of-course contain the **connection** and **parser** part, which is what you're looking for.

Agent2D is one of the base codes written by Hidehisa AKIYAMA who is also the developer of rcssserver2d. You can get it from [here](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/rctools/downloads/55186/agent2d-3.1.1.tar.gz/).

Beside that, WrightEagle team also releases their base code. You can download it from [here](http://ai.ustc.edu.cn/en/robocup/2D/releases/WrightEagleBASE-4.0.0.tar.gz).

Those two mentioned above are the most up-to-date base codes in this field. You can also get more stuff like that from [here](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/rctools/) and [here](http://wrighteagle.org/2D/).